# How can I reset the sorting of my Events in iPhoto back to by date?

Tags: photos.app, sort

I see by default iphoto orders events by the earliest date inside the event.   That being said, i see you can drag and drop events to come up with your own ordering.   Is there a way to reset the ordering back to "by date" if you have done a lot of drag and drop of events to different places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the menu select `View` > `Sort Events` > `By Date`.

Comment: thanks . . to be clear, if I switch back to Manual will that remember my last manual setup or will i have to setup taht again from scratch (as some of the picture had incorrect date)?

Comment: I have just tested this and it will revert to your custom ordering. **Assuming** you don't do more dragging. So if you have a custom order, then sort by date, then click `View` > `Sort Events` > `Manually`, it will revert to your previous manual sorting.

Comment: Also, I suggest using `Photos` > `Adjust Date and Time...` from the menu bar if you'd like to correct the cause of your issue and not just the symptom.

Comment: ah, I 100% agree . . not sure how some of these pictures were associated with these dates